# What are the security issues with setting cookies for subdomains?

Tags: http, cookies, sub-domain

Everywhere I look, I only find explanations as to who can set who's cookies and who can access the cookies of whom.

Why do we need these restrictions?
More precisely:

1. Why is it OK for a subdomain to set a cookie for a parent domain?
2. Why is it not OK for a parent domain to set a cookie for a subdomain?

Comment: Have you looked up the concept of cookie security?

Comment: Duplicate? https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/231735/cookie-domain-security

Comment: I did looked up cookie security and did not find any answer to this question security-wise. All I find is use cases and the specification for what can be done, but I'm asking for the why - why the ones who specified it this way thought that this is the most secure way? did they even think about security?

Comment: If you don't set a domain, it'll be set to the current one.  (Specific to the subdomain if that's where it's set from).  If you do set a domain, how you specify that domain will be important.  Ex: www.example.com will only be used with that domain... example.com will be used with that domain and any subdomain.  When you say why is it OK or not OK, it's not real clear what you mean by that.  You CAN set a cookie for all subdomains from the parent domain.  Just set it to example.com.

Comment: The matching rules are here: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6265#section-5.1.3  So if set, it has to match exactly OR be a suffix of the string.  (match last part...)  The security of the cookie data depends on domain matching.  (It'll be sent if it matches...)  In the old days there were a lot of sites that were hosted on subdomains of a single domain (think like geocities and tripod) and there were many cross-subdomain exploits.

Comment: Setting your cookie to the parent domain from the sub would not be a good idea if you were on one of those sites.  However, you might have a single site that uses multiple subdomains where you'd want to share cookies across the subdomains.  The site is still in control of how secure its cookie is. These days there is much more security built-in to the browsers regarding cookies.... same-site, httponly, secure, etc...

Comment: The matching rules I understand, I just don't understand the reason for why it is allowed for a subdomain to set it's parent's cookie (as it effectively means a subdomain can set cookies for all other subdomains) but its not allowed for a parent domain to set cookies for it's subdomain but it can set it's own cookie and it will be sent to the subdomain as well.

Comment: I'm looking for the security-wise logic, I'm trying to understand the motivation for these rules rather than what they do which is clear to me

Answer (score 1):

The main reason for this is security. If a website could set cookies for any other website, then it would be possible for that website to track users across the internet without their knowledge.

Another reason is that it can cause problems with how the website functions. If a website sets a cookie for a different domain, then that cookie may not be accessible when the user visits that domain. This can cause issues with login sessions, for example.

Comment: The question is about subdomains, not "any" website. Why are permissions set one way but not the other? This appears to miss the question entirely.

Comment: and this is exactly what I respond to, how are you going to know the answer to something you don't even know what is for and how it works?! Plus giving cookies to sub-domains is a big risk since they can be taken over, is not a brainer.

Comment: But then how is it possible to track a user "across the internet" if the scope is constrained to the domain? I'm trying to help you provide better answers that can more clearly address the question.

Comment: Tracking a user "across the internet" can be done using cookies, web beacons, or other tracking technologies. Web beacons can be used to track a user's activity on a website, but they can also be used to track other activities, such as what pages a user visits or what ads they click on.

Comment: Also after taking over some subdomains myself, I really find this the right way to keep a site secure. ```Congratulations! Acorns LLC has awarded $*** for your submission Subdomain takeover.

Information on final processing and payment of your submission will be sent to you shortly - so stay tuned!``` This was the last one, and only if you can scale your privilege you will gain access to the parent domain. Having cookies on it will make it easier.

Comment: I do understand how cookies works but as schroeder said, your answer doesnt address the question. I understand what is possible and not possible to do and I know the risks and what is problematic security-wise. What I dont understand is why it was defined this way the first place.

Comment: Then the problem here is not the question, because my answer is accurate but the logic, correct me if I'm wrong. what you are asking is, why do drug dealers go to jail? yes, you know they sell drugs and that is something illegal but you want to know why they go to prison, for doing something illegal. is this your question @GalSuchetzky?

Comment: no this is not my question. my question is I know that you should walk in airports with hands above your head and sunglasses are not allowed, but why is going with hands raised is a good idea and why glasses are bad and not allowed? (of course, I know on no airport with these restrictions, it's for illustration purposes only.)

Comment: ah ok now, so I did get the question logic. At this point, I guess this question will be more suable in Quora, which I think is the perfect place for it. My initial thought was you didn't know how cookies work, and you wanted to know the security part behind it, my focus was more on that.